# Single, parameterized GPO for managing group membership

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy

We have a OU design in our domain in which each "system" (web services and similar) has it's own OU, under which is nested the servers and accounts that it uses:

```
...
  + System A
    + Servers
      - SRV-A1
      - SRV-A2
    + ServiceAccounts
      - Svc-Foo
      - Svc-Bar
  + System B
    + Servers
      - SRV-B1
      - SRV-B2
    + ServiceAccounts
      - Svc-Baz
      - Svc-Qux
```

I'm trying to build a single GPO which will add "Log on as a service" on all servers in a system to all accounts under the corresponding service accounts OU. So, `Svc-Foo` and `Svc-Bar` should be able to log in as a service on `SRV-A1` and `SRV-A2`, while `Svc-Baz` and `Svc-Qux` should be able to log in as a service on `SRV-B1` and `SRV-B2`.

I *think* I should be able to do this using Item Level Targeting, but I haven't figured out how to parameterize it. Am I correct in this? And is it possible?

The domain is currently 2008R2 functional level, but we should be able to raise it to 2012R2 "quite soon", if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can achieve this - Item Level Targeting is a feature of Group Policy Preferences and, to my knowledge, there's no GPP way of assigning the "Log on as a service" rights.

If you could find an equivalent registry key, you may be able to do this but a quick Google has turned up nothing.

So, barring that, you'd need a GPO at each "System [x]" level or each "Servers" level.

Comment: I was beginning to suspect it was not possible. Unless someone has a workaround, I guess I'll have to resort to scripting them out (there are a _lot_ of these systems). Thanks, though!